# Convert a stream into mini batch for loading into bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to build the following pipeline:

```
pub/sub --> dataflow --> bigquery
```

The data is streaming, but I would like to avoid streaming the data directly into BigQuery, therefore I was hoping to batch up small chunks in the dataflow machine and then write them into BQ as a load job when they reach a certain size/time.

I cannot find any examples of how to do this using the python apache beam SDK - only Java.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid streaming it into BigQuery?!

Comment: Hey @GrahamPolley because there is a cost associated with streaming inserts, whilst load jobs are free :)

Comment: True, but it's usually negligible unless you're running at massive scale. Creating some sort of micro-batch off PubSub will require more dev time and it will have more moving components i.e. more failure points and areas to debug. Is it really worth it? If you micro-batch, you'll need to write out to GCS beforehand, and then pay for the storage too.

Answer (score 4):

This is work in progress. The `FILE_LOADS` [method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.13.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L989) is only available for batch pipelines (with the [`use_beam_bq_sink`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.13.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1118) experiments flag, it will be the default one in the [future](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues/BEAM-6928).

However, for streaming pipelines, as seen in the [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.13.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1166) it will raise a `NotImplementedError` with message:

> File Loads to BigQuery are only supported on Batch pipelines.

There is an open [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6611) where you can follow the progress.